# How to Start the windows services using Batch script(Net Start command)

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

I want to Run the batch script to start the Windows service if it crashes, so i configured the Recovery service to run a program for the First failure, Second Failure and subsequent Failure

i have a script working if i click Run as administrator or manually clicks, but the same script is not working(Shows `Access is denied`) under Run a program option in Windows Service recovery

the service is running under the Network Service account which does not have admin privilege

script-

```
@echo  on
setlocal
CD /D "C:\ServiceBatch"
set email="GUID@domain.com"
set service=LanmanWorkstation
set output=LanmanWorkstation.txt
set Subject=LanmanWorkstation 
net start %service%
sc query %service% >%output%
if errorlevel 1 (
wmailto %email% -s"%service% Started Succesfully" -t%output%
)
```

self elevated script as admin

```
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code starts)
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:: BatchGotAdmin (Run as Admin code ends)
```

Comment: What does `whois` say if you redirect it to a file?

Comment: i think whois for the domain lookup, can you tell me how to use it for my scenario ,  my issue is except the net start everything is working, i can able to query the service state and sent the email, but only the service start is showing access denied

Comment: `SC Query %service% > %output%` should return an errorlevel of `0` regardless of the service state. _`SC Query` outputs successfully to the file whether a service is running or not. Both of those are successful commands and as such should return an errorlevel of `0`_. The code should therefore never even send an email! In order to start a service you need to run the `Net Start`, or better still the `SC Start`, command as Administrator, otherwise you will receive an `Access is denied.` message with either `System error 5 has occurred.` or `[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5:` respectively.

Comment: yes , i am getting `Access is denied` error, i am searching for the option without run a command as administrator the `net start` or `SC start` should work

Comment: May I ask the reason why you're not wanting to run the batch file as Administrator?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `whoami` not `whois` . `whoami /groups` for example will list the groups the user is in but most likely you simply don't have access to control the service.

Comment: @Compo, i am adding this batch script to the service recovery which run this script automatically when the service crash and the service configured to run under NT Service account which does not have admin rights and wont provide as well,

Comment: If the script is only triggered when the service crashes, there's no need to initially query the service, _you already know it's not running_. Just send an email and either call a self elevating batch script or use runas for the service start command!

Comment: i removed the initial query and also tried the above Run as admin script not worked, also tried by creating shortcut no luck.

Comment: Until you get the code working, it's pointless trying to elevate the service start. Unless the service name doesn't exist, the `SC` command should return an `%ErrorLevel%` of `0`.

Comment: the code is working fine when i run manually but it is not starting the service when i put inside the service recovery to run a program.